# How can I order the network graph in plotly for R?

Tags: r, networking, graph, plotly

My code looks like this right now:

```
library(plotly)
library(igraph)

A <- data.frame(Category=rep("A",13))

B <- data.frame(Authors=c("John Snow, 2016 (0, 0)","Daenerys Targaryen, 2016 (0, 0)","Arya Stark, 2016 (0, 0)", "Cersei Lannister, 2016 (0, 0)","Tyrion Lannister, 2016 (1, 1)","Brienne of Tarth, 2016 (0, 0)","Theon Greyjoy, 2016 (1, 0)","Khal Drogo, 2015 (16, 0)","Bran Stark, 2015 (3, 3)"))

edgelist <- bind_cols(Category,Authors)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
L <- layout_nicely(graph)
vs <- V(graph)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(graph))
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)
Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]

txt <- list(
  family = "cambria",
  size = 10,
  color = "black",
  opacity = 1
)

txtt <- list(
  family = "cambria",
  size = 20,
  color = "black",
  opacity = 1
)

size = c(25,rep(5,length(vs)-1))


network <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", x = Xn, y = Yn, mode = "markers+text", 
               text = names(vs), hoverinfo = "text",marker=list(size=size,color='5BC0DE'), textfont = txt

)


edge_shapes <- list()
for(i in 1:Ne) {
  v0 <- es[i,]$V1
  v1 <- es[i,]$V2

  edge_shape = list(
    type = "line",
    line = list(color = "#030303", width = 0.3),
    x0 = Xn[match(v0,names(vs))],
    y0 = Yn[match(v0,names(vs))],
    x1 = Xn[match(v1,names(vs))],
    y1 = Yn[match(v1,names(vs))],
    opacity = 1
  )

  edge_shapes[[i]] <- edge_shape}

network <- layout(
  network,
  paper_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
  plot_bgcolor="#FFFFFF",
  hovermode = "closest",
  title = "Authors Network",
  titlefont=txtt,
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
  yaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE)


)


network
```

When I run this code the network generated has the nodes randomly ordered,  I would like it to be ordered exactly how it is on the code, chronologically that is, but I don't know how I can do it in this type of graphic. So if anyone could help me with that I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the seed before calling `layout_nicely` the layout will be identical every time you call it.

```
set.seed(42)
```

[image]

```
library(plotly)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
A <- data.frame(Category=rep("A",9))
B <- data.frame(Authors=c("John Snow, 2016 (0, 0)","Daenerys Targaryen, 2016 (0, 0)","Arya Stark, 2016 (0, 0)", "Cersei Lannister, 2016 (0, 0)","Tyrion Lannister, 2016 (1, 1)","Brienne of Tarth, 2016 (0, 0)","Theon Greyjoy, 2016 (1, 0)","Khal Drogo, 2015 (16, 0)","Bran Stark, 2015 (3, 3)"))

edgelist <- bind_cols(A,B)

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
L <- layout_nicely(graph)
vs <- V(graph)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(graph))
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)
Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]

network <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", 
                   x = Xn, 
                   y = Yn, 
                   mode = "markers+text", 
                   text = names(vs), 
)


edge_shapes <- list()
for(i in 1:Ne) {
  v0 <- es[i,]$V1
  v1 <- es[i,]$V2

  edge_shape = list(
    type = "line",
    line = list(color = "#030303", width = 0.3),
    x0 = Xn[match(v0,names(vs))],
    y0 = Yn[match(v0,names(vs))],
    x1 = Xn[match(v1,names(vs))],
    y1 = Yn[match(v1,names(vs))],
    opacity = 1
  )

  edge_shapes[[i]] <- edge_shape}

network <- layout(
  network,
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
  yaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE)
)

network
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if there's a way to set the order exactly as it is in the vector? @MaximilianPeters

Comment: @L.F.: Try `L <- layout_as_star(graph)`

Comment: @MaximillianPeters Thank you, it worked out perfectly!